# Tablet PC requires double tap for single click in some programs

Tags: windows-8, tablet, mouse-click

I've noticed that in some programs, you have to double-tap the screen in order for a single-click to register. In one such program, Osu, there is an option to fix this issue:

[image]

However, I still have other programs that exhibit this behavior that have no such option. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the double-click speed/delay in the Mouse properties Control Panel applet?

Comment: How is that relevant?

Comment: If it's specific to a program then that's probably how it was coded to accept input, but if it's system-wide then modifying those options might help.

Comment: I see the same behavior than OP on my SO's ASUS Transformer. I would be interested in answers to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this for *pen taps*. The same technique did not work for *touch taps*. My results are from Windows 10 Pro (I have not tried on the newer Windows 10 Creator's Edition), on a Surface Pro with completely default touch drivers.

You need to disable "press and hold for right-click".

Images and instructions copied from [ISunShare.com](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-or-enable-press-and-hold-for-right-clicking-in-win-10.html) and [Dell.com](http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln85929/sx2210t-monitor-touch-screen-tools-configuration-and-trouble-shooting-for-windows-vista-and-windows-7?lang=en) -- mirroring here for posterity.

Open Control Panel. I had to go to the "hardware and sound" section. From there: open the "Pen and Touch" control panel.

[image: Control Panel]

Open the "Pen Options" tab, and configure "Press and hold". *Here's the closest screenshot I could find:*

[image: Pen Options]

Disable press and hold for right-clicking.

[image: Press and Hold settings]

Hit OK. The "Press and Hold settings" dialog will close; you'll return to the "Pen and Touch" dialog. Hit Apply.

Now the pen driver will interpret clicks as single-clicks in all situations (instead of waiting to see whether it's a click-and-hold).